# Java database connectivity

Tags: java, mysql

While installing mysql , I changed the port no from 3306 to 3305.
Now I am trying to connect Java project in netbeans ide to mysql but it ain't working even though I tried connecting with both the port numbers

Comment: "it ain't working" is not enough to get help here. Please add more details, like what you tried so far and any error messages you are seeing.

Comment: The website isn't allowing me to add photos as it says u gotta have at least 10 reputations

Comment: add error logs..

Comment: I checked on internet..it said " you must configure the MySQL Server properties. Right-click the Databases node in the Services window and choose Register MySQL Server to open the MySQL Server Properties dialog box. "........but in my netbeans the register mysql server option is unclickable....although I installed mysql completely and correctly

Answer (score 0):

change it back to 3306, because it is the default port number for MySql. If the error remains unsolved try to reinstall it.